# How to label name for a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling, labeled

I'd like to label a name $K_4$ in following graph.  How to do that?

```
completegraph4 = ImportString["C~", "Graph6"]
```

[image]

Comment: `Graph[completegraph4, PlotLabel -> Style["K_4", 16]]`?

Comment: ... or `Labeled[completegraph4, Style["K_4", 16], Top]`?

Comment: Thanks!  I'd like to ask more, How to adjust the position of label ?

Comment: I'm wondering:  Did the OP even look at the documentation for `Graph` which answers all this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) options work in `Graph`. You can use [`PlotLabel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabel.html) or add a [`Text`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html) primitive to the [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html).

```
label = Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(K\), \(4\)]\)", 16]

CompleteGraph[4, PlotLabel -> label]

CompleteGraph[4, Epilog -> Text[label, Scaled[{0.8, 0.8}]]]
```

You could also use [`Labeled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to place the label at the top you can use the option [`PlotLabel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabel.html):

```
Graph[completegraph4, PlotLabel -> Style["K_4", 16]]
```

[image]

Or wrap the graph object with [`Labeled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html):

```
Labeled[completegraph4, Style["K_4", 16], Top]
```

[image]

```
Labeled[completegraph4, Style["K_4", 16], Right]
```

[image]

To get a finer control on label position you can use [`Legended`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html) + [`Placed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Placed.html):

```
Legended[completegraph4, Placed[Style["K_4", 16], {.8, .9}]]
```

[image]

You can also use [`Locator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Locator.html) to place the label interactively:

```
DynamicModule[{loc = {.8, .8}}, 
 Dynamic @ Show[Graph[completegraph4], Graphics[{Locator[loc, Style["K_4", 16]]}]]]
```

[image]

or

```
DynamicModule[{loc = {.8, .8}}, 
 Graph[completegraph4, Epilog -> {Dynamic@Locator[loc, Style["K_4", 16]]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: haha, Magical mma!